# Setting up this generative model for inference: uniform priors

Tags: bayesian, prior

I am trying to set up a generative model where I have two images $x$ and $y$ and it is assumed that $y$ can be generated by applying some unknown transformation to $x$ i.e.

$$
y = t(x, w) + e
$$

i.e.
$$
e = y- t(x, w)
$$

where $t$ is the applied transformation which has parameters $w$ and e is the error which is assumed to normally distributed IID noise. So, I have a likelihood term given by (for a single pixel in the image):

$$
L(w) = \prod_{i=1}^{N}(\frac{\phi}{2\pi})^{\frac{1}{2}} \exp^{\frac{-1}{2} \phi e_i^2}
$$

where $\phi$ is the noise precision. I also have a prior on the variance of $\phi$ which is modelled as a gamma distribution. Because they are independent, the likelihood terms can be multiplied as in the equation above.

Now, I know absolutely nothing about the nature of the parameters $w$, so I am guessing I should have a uniform prior on $w$? However, I do not know much about how to use these priors mathematically and $w$ can take on any value, so I am not sure how to make a proper distribution out of this uniform prior as well. I was wondering if someone could give me some advice on this. I am interested in inferring maximum mode and also characterise the spread of $w$. At the moment, I am even struggling to understand how to model things in a Bayesian setting when you have no prior belief on the form of these parameters of interest.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to express myself clearly. Components of $w$ are defined over the whole real line. $\phi$ is a scalar, so the noise precision matrix can be written as  $\phi^{-1} I$ where I is the identity matrix. $e$ is indeed a scalar, so the likelihood term needs to be edited which I will do now.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in my comment as well. $e$ is a scalar at every pixel in the image i.e. $e = y-t(x, w)$.

Comment: Sorry keep making silly mistakes....

Comment: You are right. The reason I wrote it like this is because I was doing something with the log likelihood and working on the product over the voxels and then the matrix form was more appropriate and I sort of stuck with that. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Okay, then the most obvious choice for $w$ is flat, but you could choose just make them something symmetric and unimodal but with very large variance, or maybe choose some structure that makes the w's somewhat similar in size to each other, while still heavy-tailed. The problem is choosing priors is very much reliant on expert subject knowledge that you will possess more of than I would.

Comment: So do you think a Gaussian with a very large variance centred around the identity transformation would make sense?

Comment: It *could* make sense in some situations. I'm just mentioning possibilities. You're better placed to work out what does make sense. Is it really the case that values like $(10^{10000},10^{-4000})$ would be *just* as likely as $(10^6,10^5,10^{-2})$? If not, you should consider whether you have more knowledge than you're expressing.